# Yii: How to catch the error and redirect if DB connection failed

Tags: yii

Sometimes my app fails to connect to my db.

How do I catch and redirect to a statis page?

`CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'given_db'`

Comment: For this you need to remove it from components in config and activate it manually. Other method (i dont recomend it) change open() function where CDbConnection throws exception.

Comment: @ineersa: Absolutely not.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: Yii's error handling mechanism can handle this without any trouble. Did you [read the manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error)?

Comment: yes i did; it was not mi mistakel its a issue within the rights module, module that messes with yiis controllers; maybe  a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the cleanest solution, but you can create your custom `DbConnection` component:

```
class DbConnection extends CDbConnection
{
    public function open()
    {
        try {
            parent::open();
        } catch(CDbException $e) {
            Yii::app()->request->redirect(array('site/maintenance'));
        }
    }
}
```

And then configure this as your `db` component:

```
'components' => array(
    'db' => array(
        'class' => 'DbComponent',
```

The drawbacks are:

- Will only work in the web and break your console apps
- Requires `site/maintenance` to definitely be free of any DB access or you'd end up in an infinite redirect loop

Comment: yes, i knew this but there was something wrong within my app; after i toked a closer look, it turned out that the rights module was messing the things out, because my main controllers where somehow extending the rights module, so there was a loop and the error was never cought; after doing the same way, with the basic controllers this time, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create your own 500 error page?
Check this for more info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#displaying-errors

Answer (score -1):

you can set below in components array

```
'cache' => array('class' => 'system.caching.CDbCache'),
```

Comment: And how it will help to catch error on establishing CDbConnection?